# Django - public profile with slug - how to use two user models?

Tags: python, django

I've created a public profile with slug -> .../slug of user/

My issue is how I can know if current_user (user of the slug of the page has an active story):

```
{% if current_user.story.is_active %}new_story_available{% else %}no{% endif %}
```

That does not work because current_user is related to userprofile models. Does anyone has an idea?

user.views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/cooker/login')
def userpublicpostview(request, slug):
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects.select_related('userprofile'), username=slug)
    ...
    storys = Story.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)
    return render(request, 'user_public_profile.html', {
        'current_user': user,
        ...
        'user_storys': storys,
    })
```

user/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    is_online = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_storys')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='story/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        if (self.created_on + timedelta(days=1)) > now:
            return True
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user doesn't have a single `story`, it has multiple `user_storys`:

```py
{% if current_user.user_storys.active().exists() %}new_story_available{% else %}no{% endif %}
```

Then update your `Story` model to have `active` filter:

```py
class StoryManager(models.Manager):
  def active(self):
    return self.get_queryset().filter(created_at__gt=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=1))

class Story(models.Model):
  objects = StoryManager()
  ...
```

Comment: amazing @GProst works well with {% if current_user.user_storys.active.exists %}new_story_available{% else %}no{% endif %}